# Stability test for LTV systems by differential Lyapunov inequalities

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

Consider a linear time-varying system:
\begin{equation}
\dot x(t) = A(t) x(t),  \tag{$*$}
\end{equation}
where $A(t)$ is a time-varying block matrix defined as
$$
A(t) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I\\
-\gamma M(t) & -\gamma I
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and $0 \prec \alpha I \preceq M(t) \preceq \beta I$, $M(t)$ is continuously differentiable for all $t\geq0$.

My question is:
*Can we say anything about convergence rate of $x$ towards $0$?*

I've been considering differential Lyapunov inequalities in order to prove the convergence rate. According to page 117 in [1], the linear state equation $(*)$ is uniformaly exponentially stable if there exists an $n\times n$ matrix function $P(t)$ that for all $t$ is symmetric, continuously differentiable, and such that
$$\eta I \preceq P(t) \preceq \rho I,$$
$$A^\top(t)P(t) + P(t)A(t) + \dot P(t) \preceq -v I.$$

In a recent paper, [2] shows that
$$\dot P(t) + A^\top(t)P(t) + P(t)A(t) \preceq 2\mu(t)P(t),$$
where $\mu(t)$ is uniformly exponentially stable can be used to show exponential convergence rate. The same paper also shows that if $A(t)$ is an blocked upper-triangular matrix, then it's much easier to prove exponential stability (which is not the case in this example, since $A(t)$ here is not a blocked upper-triangular matrix).

Any ideas on how to find such a matrix $P(t)$, or other suggestions?

[1] *Rugh, Wilson J.*, Linear system theory., Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall. xv, 581 p. (1996). [ZBL0892.93002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0892.93002).

[2] *Zhou, Bin*, [**On asymptotic stability of linear time-varying systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2015.12.030), Automatica 68, 266-276 (2016). [ZBL1334.93152](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1334.93152).